# Any other way to use Attribute Routing in MVC 4?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm working on MVC 4 project and i'm trying to use Attribute routing by installing AttributeRouting -Version 3.4.2 using Nuget.
But still i cannot use Attribute

`routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();`

Above code of line showing error in RouteConfig.cs file.

Comment: What error does it show?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: routes does not have any method name MapMvcAttributeRoutes().
[Error]

Comment: That Map method is an extension method. You will need a `using` directive pointing to the correct namespace. Try putting your cursor on that method and then press Ctrl+dot - maybe VS can solve your problem for you